# Equation for a circle that occurs when a plane goes through a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres

So the problem I have is that I have a sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ and a plane $$x+y+z=0$$ that goes through the center of the sphere and creates a circle. Now, what I tried was plugging in $$z=-x-y$$ into the equation for the sphere and got $$x^2+y^2+yx= 1/2$$ But this isn't a circle, it's an ellipse so somewhere I must have gone wrong.

Also, the answer is supposed to be in spherical coordinates. Should I just convert the final answer to spherical coordinates then? That would mean I would get $$ r^2\sin(\phi) + r^2 \sin(\phi)^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 1/2$$ after you plug in $$\sin(\theta)^2 + \cos(\theta)^2 = 1$$. Is that a correct transformation into spherical coordinates?

Comment: Actually that is the equation of a circle.  I'm not sure it's what you want.  The intersection is a closed curve that "lives" in three dimensions, so an equation that involves only $x,y$ as unknowns isn't technically "the" equation of that intersection.  The rest of your post suggests you want to express an equation "in spherical coordinates".  It is possible you want to get a parametric expression for the points on the circle.

Comment: No it is not correct because it is a circle in 3D with changing values of $z$ too. One way to write it is using vectors and use polar coordinates. If you are writing it in spherical coordinates, write it as parametrization using $r, \theta$ eliminating $\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ with the plane $x+y+z=0$ is simply described by those two equations. It certainly isn't $x^2+y^2+xy=\frac12$, since that defines a surface, not a line. You made no mistake in your computations, but you only have$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1\wedge x+y+z=0\implies x^2+y^2+xy=\frac12,$$and this implication is not an equivalence.

And the equation in spherical coordinates is$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\rho=1\\\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi)=0.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I meant a circular surface. Just to be clear, the spherical coordinates of $$x^2 + y^2 + xy = 1/2$$ is what you have written there in the last lines of your answer?

Comment: No. I got back to the equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y+z=0$ and expressed them in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Should the last line then be "=0" instead of "=1" like it is?

Comment: Sure! Sorry. My bad.